# AzureAD Module & PowerShell ISE - Get-AzureADUser not working in ISE

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-powershell-v2

My coworker and myself I am facing a really odd issue with PowerShell ISE: The following code simply returns `$null` when executed via PowerShell ISE, but works fine in a regular PowerShell window or in VS Code:

```
Import-Module AzureAd

Connect-AzureAD

$user = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "fooar@test.com"
```

The connection is correctly established because calling  `Get-AzureADUser -All $true` returns the expected set of users in ISE.

We are using version `2.0.0.155` of module `AzureAD`. And this is the used PowerShell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  248
```

Any idea why it is not working in ISE?

Comment: Perhaps, STA vs MTA model difference.  Does it work for you when you start powershell via `powershell -sta`?

Comment: I am getting the same behavior as described: PowerShell works, ISE doesn't. Same version of PowerShell, but `2.0.0.131` of the AzureAD module. Also, when checking `$Host.Runspace.ApartmentState` both were in STA.

Comment: Ok, last least is it not only me an my co-worker.

Comment: Same problem with AzureAD 2.0.1.16.  Super odd.  In addition, using searchstring for just `foobar` but not `foobar@example.com`